# ImportError: cannot import name TruncatedSVD

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, k-means

I am getting the following error while executing the kmeans clustering code given in the link:http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_clustering.html

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/kskt.py", line 8, in <module>
    from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
ImportError: cannot import name TruncatedSVD
```

Can anyone please help me? I'm a beginner in this area.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the version of `sklearn`

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
```

You need `0.14.x` + to use `TruncatedSVD`

No `TruncatedSVD` in [0.13.x](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.13.X/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py),
but exists in [0.14.x](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.14.X/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py)

Comment: Did you mean `0.13.X` and `0.14.X`?

Comment: Before, the same functionality was implemented in RandomizedPCA btw.